# Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth)

Tags: bluetooth, fedora

What can cause the following error. My bluetooth is working on Fedora 38

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Jun 28 08:26:31 fedora systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth).
Jun 28 08:26:39 fedora systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth).
Jun 28 08:27:11 fedora systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth).
Jun 28 08:32:59 fedora systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth).
(base) [dlovison-pc@fedora ~]$ 
``
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and multiple reboots and manually restarting the service didn't help.

Not sure whether it was a coincidence or it really had an effect, but I tried this and now Bluetooth is working again.

1. Turn off the PC.
2. Unplug power cable to PSU.
3. Hold power button for 30 seconds.
4. Plug power back into PSU.
5. Boot PC.

Found here:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bluetooth-service-was-skipped-because-of-a-failed-condition-check-conditionpathisdirectory-sys-class-bluetooth/124668/12

Original source:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/he7ci7/comment/g1przej/?context=3

Comment: Worked for me too (on Fedora 39). Other reports of it working: [endeavorOS 2023](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/unable-to-start-bluetooth-service/37439) and [Ubuntu 2020](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/aorus-master-x570-ubuntu-bluetooth/152747).

Comment: Worked for me too! The bluetooth hardware was not showing under Ubuntu nor Windows, and now it works.